# How to dynamically add data in tableview?

Tags: javafx

This are the colid specify in fxml file, I don't know the way. If I press the add button inputted data are not showing in the table view. Some blank row has been added. I want to add data in tableview from user.

```
@FXML
private TableColumn<AddItemDetails, String> colofiice_name;

@FXML
private TableColumn<AddItemDetails, String> colref_name;

@FXML
private TableColumn<AddItemDetails, String> colch_item_name;

@FXML
private TableColumn<AddItemDetails, String> colch_item_code;

@FXML
private TableColumn<AddItemDetails, String> colch_unit;

@FXML
private TableColumn<AddItemDetails, String> colch_qty;

@FXML
private TableColumn<AddItemDetails, String> colch_rec_by;

@FXML
private TableColumn<AddItemDetails, String> colch_desig;

@FXML
private TableColumn<AddItemDetails, String> colch_addr;

@FXML
private TableColumn<AddItemDetails, String> colch_remark;

@FXML
private TableColumn<AddItemDetails, String> colch_no;

@FXML
private TableColumn<AddItemDetails, String> colch_action;



private JFXCheckBox CB;
```

*I write this code in controller*

```
public void AddTableView(ActionEvent event)throws SQLException{

    AddItemDetails additem = new AddItemDetails();
    additem.setOfficeName(select_office.getValue());
    additem.setRefNo(challan_select_item.getValue());
    additem.setItemName(txt_ref_no.getText());
    additem.setItemCode(txt_item_code.getText());
    additem.setItemUnit(txt_unit.getText());
    additem.setItemQty(txt_qty.getText());
    additem.setReceiveBY(txt_rec_by.getText());
    additem.setDesignation(txt_desig.getText());
    additem.setChNo(txt_chllan.getText());
    additem.setAddress(txt_addr.getText());
    additem.setRemarks(txt_remark.getText());
    additem.setAction(CB);


    tableview2.getItems().addAll(additem);




    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

*this my AddItemDetails Class*

```
package inventory_system_app;

import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXCheckBox;
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXComboBox;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;


public class AddItemDetails {

private  String office_name;
private  String ref_no;
private  String I_name;
private  String I_code;
private  String I_unit;
private  String I_qty;
private  String rec_by;
private  String desig;
private  String ch_no;
private  String address;
private  String ch_remarks;
private JFXCheckBox Action;


public AddItemDetails(String office_name,String ref_no,String I_name,String  
I_code,String I_unit, String I_qty,String rec_by,String desig,String 
ch_no,String address, String ch_remarks, String value){

    this.office_name = office_name;
    this.ref_no = ref_no;
    this.I_name = I_name;
    this.I_code = I_code;
    this.I_unit = I_unit;
    this.I_qty = I_qty;
    this.rec_by = rec_by;
    this.desig = desig;
    this.ch_no = ch_no;
    this.address = address;
    this.ch_remarks = ch_remarks;
    this.Action = new JFXCheckBox();

}

AddItemDetails() {

}



public String getOfficeName(){ 
    return office_name;
}

public String getRefNo(){ 
    return ref_no;
}

public String getItemName(){ 
    return I_name;
}

public String getItemCode(){ 
    return I_code;
}

public String getItemUnit(){ 
    return I_unit;
}

public String getItemQty(){ 
    return I_qty;
}

public String getReceiveBY(){ 
    return rec_by;
}

public String getDesignation(){ 
    return desig;
}

public String getChNo(){ 
    return ch_no;
}

public String getAddress(){ 
    return address;
}

public String getRemarks(){ 
    return ch_remarks;
  }

   public JFXCheckBox getAction() {
    return Action;
   }


   public void setOfficeName(String value){
    this.office_name= value;
   }

     public void setRefNo(String value){
    this.ref_no=value;
    }

    public void setItemName(String value){
    this.I_name=value;
    }

    public void setItemCode(String value){
    this.I_code=value;
   }

   public void setItemUnit(String value){
    this.I_unit=value;
}

    public void setItemQty(String value){
    this.I_qty=value;
}

    public void setReceiveBY(String value){
    this.rec_by=value;
}

    public void setDesignation(String value){
    this.desig=value;
}

    public void setChNo(String value){
    this.ch_no=value;
}

  public void setAddress(String value){
    this.address=value;
}

 public void setRemarks(String value){
    this.ch_remarks=value;
}

public void setAction(JFXCheckBox Action) {
    this.Action = Action;
} 


}
```

Comment: Here : http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JavaFX/AddnewrowtoTableView.htm is a simple example, how to add a new item to your `TableView`. You have to change the `String`s in the `AddItemDetails` to StringProperties, and set the `cellValueFactory`-s to each column.

Comment: but by this process when i add new item the previous one is replace by current data. the observable list is replaced by the current data. i want to display all the data in the tableview added by end the user

Comment: Then there is something you are not showing.

Comment: Did you set the cell value factories for your columns? If so - please provide a [mcve].

Comment: previously i have pass the user data like this `ch_data.add(new AddItemDetails(Office_name,Ref_name,Item_name,Item_Code,Item_Unit,Item_Qty,rec_by,Desig,Ch_no,Address,Remarks,""));` after that i have set value factory like this `colofiice_name.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(cellData.getValue().getOfficeName()));`  that didn't work as each time the new data is replace by the new one. where ch_data is observable list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps to make your code working:

1.
 In the `AddItemDetails` replace every `String` field which you want to show in the table with `StringProperty`es like:

```
    public class AddItemDetails {

    private  StringProperty office_name;
    private  StringProperty ref_no;
    private  StringProperty I_name;
    .
    .
    .


    public AddItemDetails(String office_name,String ref_no,String I_name,...){

    this.office_name = new SimpleStringProperty(office_name);
    this.ref_no = new SimpleStringProperty(ref_no);
    this.I_name = new SimpleStringProperty(I_name);
    .
    .
    .
    //  + getters
```

2. Setting the `cellValueFactory`-s for each column:

   ```
   colofiice_name.setCellValueFactory(data -> data.getValue().office_nameProperty());
   colref_name.setCellValueFactory(data -> data.getValue().colref_nameProperty());
   item_name.setCellValueFactory(data -> data.getValue().item_nameProperty());
   ```
3. Adding a new item to the tableView:

   ```
   tableView.getItems().add(new AddItemDetails("Office","Ref","I_name",...));
   ```

After these steps it should work.

**EDIT**

You can use an 
`ObservableList<AddItemDetails> myData = FXCollecctions.observableArraylist();`

for storing the data, then:

```
tableView.setItems(myData);
```

then you can add and remove elements to and from this list, and it will update the data in tableview too.Like:

```
mydata.add(new AddItemDetails(...));
myData.remove(...);
```

Comment: `tableView.getItems().add(new AddItemDetails(Office_name,Ref_name,Item_name,Item_Code,Item_Unit,Item_Qty,rec_by,Desig,Ch_no,Address,Remarks,""));` where Office_name is  `String Office_name = txt_field.getText(); ` should i try like this.

Comment: Exactly, but if you don't respect the first two steps it won't work.

Comment: I have one more question how I can add tableview data into observable list so that i can perform remove data by selecting checkbox from tableview like this `private void DeleteAddTableRow(ActionEvent event){
Connection con = dc.Connect();        
ObservableList<AddItemDetails>dataListRemove = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            for(AddItemDetails bean: ch_data){
            if(bean.getAction().isSelected()){   
              dataListRemove.add(bean);    
            }          
         }
           data.removeAll(dataListRemove);
       
}`

Comment: I've updated the answer, you take a look if it solves the delete prblem

Comment: `tableView.getItems().add(new AddItemDetails("Office_name","Ref","I_name",...));`  instead of this line should i use this `mydata.add(new AddItemDetails("Office","Ref","I_name",...));` where Office_name is `String Office_name = txt_field.getText();`